# effective back-up using Raid / Win7 back-up

Tags: windows-7, backup, data-recovery, raid-1

I have a stand-alone pc system with two 2 tb harddiscs, one of which configured as Raid1, i.e. mirorring. The operational drive is partitioned. I use an external 1 tb harddisc for back-up using Windows 7 back-up facility which will be swapped weekly and stored on other premises. I back-up all partitions AND allow a system back-up. All application software is on the C: partition.

Questions:
How can I see whether Raid1 is working; i.e. is doing its job. All I see now is a status message in the start-up procedure that says its status is normal. How can I see used or available space on Raid 1?
The Win-7 backup allows for 1 schedule only as far as I can see. I want daily back-ups of data. However due to the single schedule I am forced to do the time-consuming system back-up and c: back-up as well. Is there a way to activate two schedules allowing a frequent (daily) data back-up and a system back-up with c: drive back-up on a say weekly basis?
Of course it can be forced by hand but I am likely to forget that.

I am not the programming type of person so looking for simple and controllable solutions. Thank you - any help is apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To tell if the RAID function is working, you could physically swap the two drives over? They should be identical, so just swapping the SATA ports on the motherboard should allow the system to boot and run as normal, as the BIOS will read from the SATA port that it was reading from before the swap... someone correct me if that's not a failsafe way of checking, but I think that should work.

Comment: Thanks Jay,I understand what you are saying but that is too complicated at my level. What you are saying sounds quite logical, on the other hand there should be an easier method methinks because the other implication of your answer is that the proper functioning of the RAID cannot be seen and thus we can but hope it works? Regards

Comment: in Windows 7 press the start key and start typing "disk management". The Windows Disk Management program should appear in the menu. Open this to see if the second (mirror) disk is visible. If it is visible, Windows should tell you the amount of free space there is left on it. If it has exactly the same amount of free space as the active disk then I would say the RAID 1 function is working. I am no specialist on RAID though... Hope that helps.